# Upload a file to a google drive link using python

Tags: python, file-upload, google-drive-api

Given a google drive link, how to upload a file in that directory using python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload a file to Google Drive using a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830820/how-to-upload-a-file-to-google-drive-using-a-python-script)

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.   Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `google-api-python-client`, see [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python).

You probably want to use the [create method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create), e.g. like this:

```
file_metadata = {'name': 'photo.jpg'}
media = MediaFileUpload('files/photo.jpg',
                        mimetype='image/jpeg')
file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                    media_body=media,
                                    fields='id').execute()
print 'File ID: %s' % file.get('id')
```

Code taken from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads).